# First EventEmitter Causing Second Not To Fire

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a method that is firing two different events. The second event is not being triggered. However, when I comment out he first event from being emitted, the second one fires as expected.

If I reduce the code down to just this:

```
public async approve() {
     this.isLoadingChange.emit(true);
     this.actionPerformed.emit();
}
```

both events work fine.

Here is the method I am calling on the child component:

```
    public async approve() {
        try {
        this.isLoadingChange.emit(true);

            await this._letterService.approveLetter(this.letter.letterQueueId);
            this._toastrService.success('Successfully approved letter.', 'Success');
        } catch(ex) {
            this._toastrService.error('Something went wrong. Could not approve letter.', 'Error');
            console.error(ex);
        } finally {
            console.log("finally?");
            this.actionPerformed.emit();
        }
    }
```

And here are my events on the parent:

```
    public async onActionPerformed($event) {
        console.log("action performed", this.isLoading);
        if($event) {
            this.request.templateIds = [$event.templateId];
            this.request.hashValue = $event.hashValue;
            this.filterPatternTemplate = `TemplateId: ` + this.request.templateIds[0];
            this.filterPatternHash = `Hash: ` + this.request.hashValue;
        }
        await this.performSearch();
        console.log("search complete", this.isLoading);
    }

    public async onIsLoadingChange(newValue: boolean) {
        console.log(newValue);
        this.isLoading = newValue;
    }
```

Comment: Is your first emit returning a promise? the await keyword won't let your code continue until the first promise is returned.

Comment: `console.log("finally?")` is being logged in console?

Comment: @sabithpocker yes

Comment: @Rager the first emit does not return a promise.

Comment: What about "action performed" and "search complete" are they logged?

Comment: @sabithpocker no, they are not

Comment: So the issue is in `this.actionPerformed.emit()` can you show how this is caught and how you are invoking `onActionPerformed()`, Also try `this.actionPerformed.emit(null)` to see if an argument is expected by your code. Did you look for any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expected. The root cause should be the `await`

According to [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is fulfilled.

So your second method will not execute until promise is fulfilled.

Note: Above apply to `this.actionPerformed.emit();` method as well. As it also a async function. So you maybe wait for `this.performSearch();` finish first. As for why you don't need wait once you remove `this.isLoadingChange.emit(true);` . This maybe depends on your business logic.

Comment: Shouldn't the promise be fufilled by the time it hits the finally block?

Comment: Yes. If you say `finally?` is logged. Then must be some other reason. Can you log it after `this.actionPerformed.emit();` ? See if before and after log both works or not.

Comment: Yes, console log executes both before and after I am calling `this.actionPerformed.emit()`